Featured Image not displaying in elementor widget
I am working in elementor and I grabbed a featured image widget into the container but the image is not showing, kindly assist me. View attached image.


You'll need to check with Elementor's support team. Third-party plugin and theme support is off topic here.

@PatJ Ohk no problem

Many Times this type of problem also occur due to cache plugin so if you are using any cache plugin so disable that cache plugin and see again weather issue is fixed or not

Ohk, i eventually had to use a post widget instead of the image widget to dynamically pull a random image from my posts.
